# When deleting a struct, do I get back the gas of setting the attributes of the struct to 0, or only for the struct itself?

Tags: struct, gas-refund

I have a `mapping(bytes32=> exampleStruct) public myMapping` where:

```
struct exampleStruct {
    address owner,
    uint256 number,
    uint256 anotherNumber
}
```

To optimize gas sometimes I delete struct as in:

```
delete myMapping[structHash];
```

Is this optimal to get gas refunds or should I do:

```
delete myMapping[structHash].owner;
delete myMapping[structHash].number;
delete myMapping[structHash].anotherNumber;
delete myMapping[structHash];
```

Answer (score 1):

only use `delete myMapping[structHash];`